# Cloning an element raises error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: html, django, jquery-select2

I am using Django and in a template page, user can add multiple rows dynamically to enter values:

```html
    <div class="mb-4 row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="product_id[]" required class="form-select select2">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Product</option>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <option value="{{ product.id }}">{{ product.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% if form.type.errors %}
                <small class="text-danger">{{ form.type.errors.0 }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Qty"
                   class="form-control" required>
            {% if form.quantity.errors %}
                <small class="text-danger">{{ form.quantity.errors.0 }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="number" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Unit Price" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is a select, uses select2 library to let user search on list items.

Also add button lets user to add a new row with this script:

```js
function add_new_row() {
    var formsetContainer = document.getElementById("formset-container");

    // Clone the last invoice item row
    var lastRow = formsetContainer.lastElementChild;
    var newRow = lastRow.cloneNode(true);

    // Update IDs and clear values in the cloned row
    var prefix = "form-" + formsetContainer.childElementCount; // Assuming 1-based index
    updateRow(newRow, prefix);

    // Append the new row to the formset container
    formsetContainer.appendChild(newRow);

    // Reinitialize Select2 on the cloned select element
    $(newRow).find('select[name="product_id[]"]').select2();
}

function updateRow(row, prefix) {
    // Update IDs and clear values in the cloned row
    row.querySelectorAll("[name]").forEach(function (element) {
        // Check if the element should be excluded from value clearing
        if (!shouldExcludeElement(element)) {
            // Update IDs
            element.id = element.id.replace(/-\d+-/, "-" + prefix + "-");
            // Clear values
            element.value = "";
        }
    });

    // Add any additional logic to handle nested elements or specific event listeners
}

// Function to determine whether an element should be excluded
function shouldExcludeElement(element) {
    // Customize this condition based on the elements you want to exclude
    return (
        element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "select" && element.name === "product_id[]"
    );
}
```

Cloning works fine, except when user creates a new line, the select list doesn't open and browser console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function
```

This line raises the error:

```
$(newRow).find('select[name="product_id[]"]').select2();
```

I checked jquery duplication, linking to select2 library after jquery, importing select2 js and css. Error still there.

At the same page, `select2` works fine on the elements that are not cloned.
I dont use formset and I dont want to use it.